# Statistical Signifance Test for Regression Models

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I have two systems A and B both of which are regression models.

I predict  N items, using system A and system B using the same query points (X).

I want to check if system A comes from the same distribution in system B.

since I am using these systems to predict N items, I was going to use either a sign test, or a re-sampling test.

are these significance tests appropriate for my use case?

Comment: Can't you just check if the predictions are the same? Obviously if they are not, then they are not from the same distribution

Comment: the models are probabilistic, so not really, the predictions might be different, but the difference might not be statistically significant.

Comment: Regression models should give you the same prediction for the same output every time, no?